# Woocommerce Coupon for Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to create 2 fields similar to "product categories" and "exclude categories" for a coupon ?

I have a custom taxonomy called **brand** for Woocommerce Products, and I want to replicate this functionality for brands.